# Chrome and Firefox render percentage font size for textarea differently

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I set the font-size style of a `<textarea>` to `120%`. But the text turns out to be much bigger under Firefox compared to that under Chrome.

After checking the style using developer's tool I found the following preset style under Chrome:

```
input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
   margin: 0em;
   font: normal normal normal 13.3333330154419px/normal Arial;
   color: initial;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   word-spacing: normal;
   text-transform: none;
   text-indent: 0px;
   text-shadow: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: start;
}
```

It seems that under Chrome the `120%` is computed against 13.333px, while Firefox will computed it against the real default font-size `16px` and finally make the text appears much bigger.

I do use css reset to override the default style but Chrome insists computing `120%` against the `13.333px` preset font size.

Please anyone tell me how can I make Firefox and Chrome render **percent font size** in textarea the same?

Comment: you can make a try with: font-size:1.2rem;

Comment: These are the same size in my Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/67k0yhqz/1/  Have you set the font-family to be the same?